# Prog Challenge - Find paths to files called from configuration files or scripts

Tags: shell, parsing, scripting

I have no idea how to do that, so I come here for help :) Here is what I'd need. I need to parse some configuration files or bash/sh scripts on a Red Hat Linux system, and look for the paths to the files/commands/scripts meant to be **executed** by them. The configuration files can have different syntax or be using different languages.

Here are the files I have to look at:

Config scripts:

> - /etc/inittab
> - /var/spool/cron/root
> - /var/spool/cron/tabs/root
> - /etc/crontab
> - /etc/xinetd.conf
> - Files located under /etc/cron.d/* recursively

Bash / Sh scripts:

> - Files located under /etc/init.d/* or /etc/rc.d/* recursively. These folders contain only shell scripts so maybe all the other files listed above need separate treatment.

Now here's the challenges that I can think of:

- The paths within the files may be absolute or relatives ;
- The paths within the files may be at the beginning of lines or preceded by a character such as space, colon or semicolon ;
- File paths expressed as arguments to commands/scripts must be ignored ;
- Paths to directories must be ignored ;
- Shell functions or built-in commands must be ignored ;

Some examples (extracted from /etc/init.d/avahi-daemon):

```
if [ -s /etc/localtime ]; then
    cp -fp /etc/localtime /etc/avahi/etc >/dev/null 2>&1
```

-> Only `/bin/cp` and `/bin/[` must be returned in the snippet above (its the only commands actually executed)

```
AVAHI_BIN=/usr/sbin/avahi-daemon
$AVAHI_BIN -r
```

-> `/usr/sbin/avahi-daemon` must be returned, but only because the variable is called after.

Note that I do not have access to the actual filesystem, I just have a copy of the files to parse.

After writing this up, I realize how complicated it is and unlikely to have a 100% working solution... But if you like programming challenges :)

The good part is I can use any scripting language: bash/sh/grep/sed/awk, php, python, perl, ruby or a combination of these..

I tried to start writing up in PHP but I am struggling to get coherent results.

Thanks!

Comment: "Only /bin/cp must be returned in the snippet above (its the only command actually executed)" - Not quite. `/bin/[` is also executed. :)

Comment: Totally right, I'll edit the post... Cheers!

Comment: @Amadan: on what system is `/bin/[` a thing?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: AFAIK, every UNIX-like system: Linux, OS X... `[` has always been an executable. (In contrast, `[[ ... ]]` is a shell builtin construct.)  -- oops, sorry, it's `/usr/bin/[` on some systems (like Debian); Mac has it at `/bin/[`.

Comment: @Amadan: Yes, `/usr/bin/[` is a thing, but even that is not actually invoked by Bash when you use `[]`.  It's much more efficient for Bash to implement such things internally.  Bash also implements `test` internally: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Huh, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

The language you use to implement this doesn't matter.  What matters is that the problem is *undecidable*, because it is equivalent to the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Just as we know that it is impossible to determine if a program will halt, it is impossible to know if a program will call another program.  For example, you may think your script will invoke X then Z, but if X never returns, Z will never be invoked.  Also, you may not notice that your script invokes Y, because the string Y may be determined dynamically and never actually appear in the program text.

There are other problems which may stymie you along the way, too, such as:

```
python -c 'import subprocess; subprocess.call("ls")'
```

Now you need not only a complete parser for Bash, but also for Python.  Not to mention solve the halting problem in Python.

In other words, what you want is not possible.  To make it feasible you would have to *significantly* reduce the scope of the problem, e.g. "Find everything starting with /usr/bin or /bin that isn't in a comment".  And it's unclear how useful that would be.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree about your python example, but such thing can be safely ignored in my situation, because it's unlikely to be present in the files that I have to parse. As for the halting problem, it's not really a problem for me. I need to find the files that can be potentially executed by the script in any situation, no  matter if they are actually not executed because a statement may be hanging the execution flow before.

Comment: Right, so what about the case where a command is built dynamically?  What if a script runs `sort` by `$x$y` where `x=so` and `y=rt`?  Even if you can answer this, we are still a *long* way from done--I can come up with dozens of cases, some less contrived, that will vex you.  This entire business should be reconsidered.

Comment: You're right, I cannot answer that. I guess I'll have to accept that it will never be 100% reliable because there are so many special cases.

Comment: @jrm: A different idea would be to instrument one run of the actual programs using `strace` or similar, to actually find out what programs (or even files in general) are being used.  E.g. you can run `strace -f bash ... | grep execve` and see what execve() calls are made.  That's probably easier to implement and maybe more reliable.